# Issue with deleting dynamically created textboxes in a userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

My issue concerns deleting textboxes dynamically on my userform. On the userform there is a spin button which the user can use to create textboxes at their discretion. As I spin the spin button upwards it will create text boxes up to a maximum amount which I set. However when I spin the button backwards it will only delete the most recently created text box and will not delete any more.

The Code creating the boxes is as follows

```
Private Sub AgendaFromBox_Change()
Dim BoxValue As Integer
BoxValue = AgendaFromBox.Value
    If BoxValue > 10 Then
        AgendaFromBox.Value = 10
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If BoxValue = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Dim NewBox As Control
Dim NewLabel As Control
For i = 1 To BoxValue
Set NewBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
Set NewLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With NewBox
        .Name = "AgendaBox" & i
        .Top = 100 + 30 * i
        .Left = 20
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 20
        .ControlSource = "'Hidden'!C" & 2 + i
    End With
    With NewLabel
        .Name = "AgendaLabel" & i
        .Top = 100 + 30 * i
        .Left = 5
        .Width = 14
        .Height = 20
        .Caption = i & "."
    End With
Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B" & 2 + i) = i
Next i

NumOutBefore = BoxValue



End Sub
```

This code is part of a change event for a textbox that is linked to the spin button. The code for deleting the boxes is as follows.

```
Private Sub AgendaFromSpinner_Change()
AgendaFromBox.Value = AgendaFromSpinner.Value
Dim BoxValue1 As Integer
Static NumOutBefore As Integer
BoxValue1 = AgendaFromBox.Value

If BoxValue1 > 9 Then Exit Sub
If BoxValue1 < 1 Then Exit Sub
If BoxValue1 < NumOutBefore Then
    Controls.Remove "AgendaBox" & i
    Controls.Remove "AgendaLabel" & i
End If

NumOutBefore = AgendaFromSpinner.Value

End Sub
```

This code is part of the spin button change event. Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set a break point on the first line of your code to step through & see what all your values are? I'm speculating that `NumOutBefore = AgendaFromSpinner.Value` isn't getting set to what you expect it will be the next time the code is called, so your inner most `If..Then` is evaluating `False`, therefore the `.remove` statements are never executing.

Comment: For all I can tell they are executing, or they are at least once because it is deleting the most recently created box, just not any more than that first one. To the best of my knowledge the 'If..Then' statement is executing. I used the break point and creative use of 'MsgBox' to confirm this.

Comment: What triggers `AgendaFromBox_Change()`? Is this a text box that the user types in a number from 1 to 10?

Comment: In the `AgendaFromSpinner_Change()` event `AgendaFromBox.Value = AgendaFromSpinner.Value`, so when the spin button is clicked it changes the value in the text boxes triggering the `AgendaFromSpinner_Change()` Event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what's happening in your code. If you set a break point on the first line of each module, then step through the code after clicking the spinner up/down buttons, you should be able to verify this:

1. Spinner starts at 0
2. Click the spinner *UP* button.

   1. Spinner value is incremented
   2. Box value is incremented.
   3. `AgendaFromBox_Change()` gets triggered and builds `AgendaBox1`
3. Spinner *UP* button is clicked

   1. Spinner value is incremented
   2. Box value is incremented.
   3. `AgendaFromBox_Change()` gets triggered and builds `AgendaBox1` & `AgendaBox2`

      - You now have **2** copies of `Agendabox1`.
      - Since VBA won't like that, the second one gets automatically renamed to something
4. Spinner *UP* button is clicked

   1. Spinner value is incremented
   2. Box value is incremented.
   3. `AgendaFromBox_Change()` gets triggered and builds `AgendaBox1`, `AgendaBox2` & `AgendaBox3`

      - You now have **2** copies of `Agendabox2` and **3** copies of `AgendaBox1`
      - VBA automatically renames the duplicates to something
5. Spinner *DOWN* button is clicked

   1. Spinner value is decremented
   2. Box value is decremented.
   3. `AgendaFromBox_Change()` gets triggered and builds *another* `AgendaBox1` & `AgendaBox2`

      - You now have **4** copies of `AgendaBox1`, two of them with randomly assigned names and **3** copies of `AgendaBox2`
      - Names might not be random, but they're not what you're expecting.
   4. `AgendaFromSpinner_change()` continues to execute, deletes `AgendaBox3`
6. Spinner *DOWN* button is clicked

   1. Spinner value is decremented
   2. Box value is decremented.
   3. `AgendaFromBox_Change()` gets triggered and builds *another* `AgendaBox1`

      - You now have **5** copies of `AgendaBox1`
   4. `AgendaFromSpinner_change()` continues to execute, deletes `AgendaBox2`, but there's already at least one other `AgendaBox2something` that remains visible, so it looks like it didn't delete it.

To solve the issue, this should work:

```
Private Sub AgendaFromBox_Change()
Static BoxValue As Integer
    if BoxValue > AgendaFromBox.Value then
      'we need to update BoxValue no matter what
      BoxValue = AgendaFromBox.Value
      'we're decrementing the spinner - we don't need to do anything else here
      Exit sub
    else
      'we need to update BoxValue no matter what
      BoxValue = AgendaFromBox.Value
    end if
    If BoxValue > 10 Then
        AgendaFromBox.Value = 10
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If BoxValue = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Dim NewBox As Control
Dim NewLabel As Control

    Set NewBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
    Set NewLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With NewBox
        .Name = "AgendaBox" & boxvalue
        .Top = 100 + 30 * boxvalue
        .Left = 20
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 20
        .ControlSource = "'Hidden'!C" & 2 + boxvalue
    End With
    With NewLabel
        .Name = "AgendaLabel" & boxvalue
        .Top = 100 + 30 * boxvalue
        .Left = 5
        .Width = 14
        .Height = 20
        .Caption = boxvalue & "."
    End With
    Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B" & 2 + i) = boxvalue

'not sure where this came from or what it does.
'I don't see it declared anywhere
NumOutBefore = BoxValue

End Sub
```

My guess is that you do NOT have `Option Explicit` declared in your module or that `NumOutBefore` is declared publicly at the top of the module. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` declared - it will save trouble later

Comment: You explanation is informative and your solution is elegant. Thank you so much. (That means it worked)

Comment: Glad I could help! An upvote on the answer is nice, too.  :)  Always remember, that debugger is your friend. `F8` will help you find a lot of things that otherwise appear wonky